# What happens with my Flash player video

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, flash

Like what i said before my Flash player looks like crashed..
There is some screenshot 
http://en.zimagez.com/full/636a6be2bf925a96329a618ec91320d49c925a512148ccde6924c0fb25bf0a9de64d673426bed6962b0e01f933229b96373c19c3d88eba72.php
anyone pls tell me how to fix it..
i'm using lubuntu 13.04.. using very old PC

Comment: I can't see the image when I click the link I get an error "URL pereemee" To post screenshots see this post [How do you upload a screenshot?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6797/107450).  If you use the "img" button the image is hosted on this site so everyone can see it

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of problems getting flash to work on an older machine.

I am using 12.04, but I have had to install version 10,3,183,90 to get my flash working correctly.